# Eloquent Query always returns null for parent table using oneToOne relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, one-to-one

Parent Table

```
users
schema | 'id','email','pass'
```

Relationship

```
 public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile','user_id');
    }
```

Other Table

```
profiles
schema | 'id','user_id'/*foreign key to users table */ ,'address','city'
```

Relationship

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id');
    }
```

I'm querying `Profile` model and would like it to eagerload with `User` model.

```
public function edit($id){
$profile = \App\Profile::with('user')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
                dd($profile);
}
```

So that I can load the profile of the user for editing, alongwith the details data from `User` model like `email` & `pass` etc.

This Returns a null relation for `user` ??

Also, in blade while acessing `$profile->user->email` gives error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel1\resources\views\profile\edit.blade.php)

Here is the `dd()` output http://bit.ly/1dA0R5p

It returns null with `user` relation which is what i suspect causes `undefined property`error in blade.

Is this approach possible? Are my relations correct?

P.S. Earlier I had a vice-versa case while Querying `User` model and eagerload `Profile` model and that worked.
Snippet

```
 $users = \App\User::with('group','profile')->get(); //This was working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive `null` for because your relation definition is wrong. Your `profile` model should be

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

The error is because you are trying to get the `user` object from a collection.

Since you have used `get()` to retrieve data you are receiving a collection of profiles, not a single profile. If you want a single profile use the `first()` method instead of `get()`, else use it inside a loop.

```
@foreach ($profiles as $profile)
   {{ $profile->user->email }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: That worked. Quick followup question in `belongsTo` relation from `profile` model , the 2nd parameter should be the `key` to identify the user on `users` table right? So should i also create a `profile_id` foreign key in `users` table ??

Comment: Yes it is foreign key. Nope it doesn't work that way. `belongsTo` relations use the current table's foreign key to get the relation data. So having `user_id` on `profiles` table is enough. No need for a `profile_id` on `users` table.

Comment: That clarified. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `use SoftDeletes;` if this line is present in child Model.

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\User;
class Profile extends Model
{
//    use SoftDeletes;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'profile';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['address', 'user_id'];

protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}    
}
```

And now set `$primaryKey = 'user_id';`

In oparent Model:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

And so you can retrieve user profile

```
$profile = $user->profile? : new Profile;
```